# Combine the output of two Cypher statements with aggregation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have separate cypher queries as follows:

```
Q1: START m=node(30) MATCH (m)-[d:define]->(n) where d.start=4 RETURN n.name,COUNT(d) as count
Q2: START m=node(30) MATCH (m)-[d:define]->(n) where d.start=5 RETURN n.name,COUNT(d) as count
```

which return the following sample results:

from Q1:

```
a | 2
b | 1
c | 4
d | 3
```

from Q2:

```
a | 1
b | 1
c | 4
e | 2
```

I can process the results offline and generate a combined count, but can I combine the two cypher queries above so that I can get the following merged counts from d.start 4 and 5?

```
a | 2 | 1
b | 1 | 1
c | 4 | 4
d | 3 | 0
e | 0 | 2
```

What I have so far: how can I continue on the name and the count(d) to the next phase?

```
START m=node(30) 
MATCH (m)-[d:define]->(n) 
where d.start=4
WITH m, COLLECT (n.name, COUNT(d)) as from1
MATCH (m)-[d:define]->(n) 
where d.start=5
WITH m, COLLECT (n.name, COUNT(d)) as from2
```

A union doesn't work for me as I don't want to just union the results together. I need to separate the counts coming from d.start=4 and 5 resulting in more like an intersection.

Comment: Your question seems to have a several typos. For example, Q1 and Q2 define `A` but never use it. Your final query counts `c`, which is not defined anywhere. Can you at least correct these problems and provide sample data that gives the results you show? (Also, in recent versions of Cypher, you can no longer use `START` in the way you are using it -- but that is relatively easy to fix).

Comment: You're solution is not that far off. You do not have to use collect, simply use `COUNT(d1) as from1` in the first `WITH` clause and use `RETURN m, from1, ...` instead of the second `WITH`.

Comment: @cybersam sorry about the typos, fixed them. I'm using an old version of Cypher hence the start.

Comment: I fixed 3 remaining typos in your bottom query.

Answer (score 2):

This query should do what you want:

```
MATCH (m)-[d:define]->(n)
WHERE ID(m) = 30 AND d.start IN [4, 5]
RETURN n.name AS name, REDUCE(c = [0, 0], x IN COLLECT(d.start) |
  CASE WHEN x = 4 THEN [c[0]+1, c[1]] ELSE [c[0], c[1]+1] END) AS counts
ORDER BY name;
```

You can test it by first creating your sample data:

```
CREATE (m:Foo), (a:Foo {name: 'a'}), (b:Foo {name: 'b'}), (c:Foo {name: 'c'}), (d:Foo {name: 'd'}), (e:Foo {name: 'e'}),
  (m)-[:define {start:4}]->(a),
  (m)-[:define {start:4}]->(a),
  (m)-[:define {start:4}]->(b),
  (m)-[:define {start:4}]->(c),
  (m)-[:define {start:4}]->(c),
  (m)-[:define {start:4}]->(c),
  (m)-[:define {start:4}]->(c),
  (m)-[:define {start:4}]->(d),
  (m)-[:define {start:4}]->(d),
  (m)-[:define {start:4}]->(d),
  (m)-[:define {start:5}]->(a),
  (m)-[:define {start:5}]->(b),
  (m)-[:define {start:5}]->(c),
  (m)-[:define {start:5}]->(c),
  (m)-[:define {start:5}]->(c),
  (m)-[:define {start:5}]->(c),
  (m)-[:define {start:5}]->(e),
  (m)-[:define {start:5}]->(e);
```

With the above data (and assuming that the query uses the correct `ID` for `m`), the query returns:

```
+---------------+
| name | counts |
+---------------+
| "a"  | [2,1]  |
| "b"  | [1,1]  |
| "c"  | [4,4]  |
| "d"  | [3,0]  |
| "e"  | [0,2]  |
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE ID(n) = 30
MATCH (m)-[d:define]->(n) 
where d.start=4
WITH m, COLLECT([n.name, COUNT(c)]) as from1
MATCH (m)-[d:define]->(n) 
where d.start=5
WITH m, from1 + COLLECT([n.name, COUNT(c)]) as from2
UNWIND from2 AS row
WITH row[0] AS name, row[1] AS ct
RETURN name, SUM(ct)
```

Though I'm not totally sure if this will return the counts you expect, because you start by finding `n`, but then carry `m` forward instead, so that `(m)-[d]->(n)` path will match fundamentally different patterns. You're on the right track, though; just keep adding things to a collection until you've got all your result rows, then unwind the one big collection and perform your aggregation or other analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can ditch `COLLECT` and only use `COUNT`.

Example dataset:

```
CREATE
  (m {name: 1}),
  (m)-[:define {start: 4}]->({name: 2}),
  (m)-[:define {start: 4}]->({name: 3}),
  (m)-[:define {start: 5}]->({name: 4})
```

Query:

```
MATCH (m)-[d:define]->()
WHERE d.start=4 
WITH m, COUNT(d) as from1
MATCH (m)-[d:define]->()
WHERE d.start=5
RETURN m.name, from1, COUNT(d) as from2
```

Result:

```
╒══════╤═════╤═════╕
│m.name│from1│from2│
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│1     │2    │1    │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```